# C++: the easiest way to handle comma-delimited strings whose substrings have commas themselves?

Tags: c++, string, parsing

Here's an example:

`str1 = "a, b, \"c, d, e\", f"`

If I were to parse this string:

```
stringstream ss(str1);
while (getline(ss,str,',')){
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

The output would look like:

```
a
 b
 "c
 d
 e"
 f
```

Where I'm looking for

```
a
 b
 c, d, e
 f
```

Comment: first thing that comes to mind would be using regex to parse the input
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex
this way you can define what is a string.

Comment: `the easiest way` - Find a library on github that does that. Use that library.

Comment: This is the standard csv format, so yes, use a standard CSV library

Answer (score 1):

As they advise you in the comment, the easiest way is to use a parser library.

One of the best parser libraries in C++ is [Boost.Spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html).

Here is a working example of how to parse your format with Boost.Spirit:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_parse.hpp>

#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/variant/get.hpp>

using Element = boost::variant<
    std::string,
    std::vector<std::string>
    >;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Element const& e) {
    switch(e.which()) {
    case 0:
        return s << boost::get<std::string>(e);
    case 1:
        for(auto const& a : boost::get<std::vector<std::string>>(e))
            s << a << ' ';
        return s;
    }
    throw;
}

std::vector<Element> parse(std::string const& input) {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
    using namespace std;
    using I = decltype(input.begin());
    using S = qi::space_type;

    struct string2 : string {
        using string::string;
        string2(char c) : string(1, c) {} // Need this extra constructor for +qi::alnum.
    };

    // Grammar.
    qi::rule<I, S, string2>         element        = +qi::alnum;
    qi::rule<I, S>                  open           = qi::lit('"');
    qi::rule<I, S>                  close          = qi::lit('"');
    qi::rule<I, S, vector<string>>  nested_element = open >> (element % ',') >> close;
    qi::rule<I, S, Element>         element2       = element | nested_element;
    qi::rule<I, S, vector<Element>> parser         = element2 % ',';

    vector<Element> result;

    auto cur = input.begin();
    if(!phrase_parse(cur, input.end(), parser, qi::space, result) || cur != input.end())
        throw "Failed to parse.";

    return result;
}

int main() {
    auto elements = parse("a, b, \"c, d, e\", f");
    for(auto const& e : elements)
        std::cout << e << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c d e 
f
```

Comment: @sehe Do you know how to avoid having to specify `qi::rule<I, S, ...>`, using `auto` doesn't work?

Comment: I think `Element = boost::variant<` might be slight overkill, I suspect this is a csv, so you don't have to parse elements wrapped in `""`.